# JMC does not launch on mac osx

Tags: java, jmc

I downloaded jdk1.7.0_45.jdk on mac osx 10.7.5 so I could use JMC. It started up once, and I was able to connect to a vm, but after the first time, it just hangs once the splash screen launches. I tried to turn debug with the -debug flag, but don't see any output anywhere. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
Alpers-MacBook-Pro:bin aakture$ ./jmc -debug -consoleLog
Start VM: -XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:+FlightRecorder
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Djava.class.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/Java Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os macosx
-ws cocoa
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/Java Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/jmc
-name Jmc
--launcher.library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/Java Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807/eclipse_1503.so
-startup /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/Java Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-debug
-consoleLog
-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk
-vmargs
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:+FlightRecorder
-XstartOnFirstThread
file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
file:/Users/aakture/.eclipse/906589807/configuration/
Configuration file:
file:/Users/aakture/.eclipse/906589807/configuration/config.ini loaded
Shared configuration location:
file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/configuration/
Framework located:
file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar
Framework classpath:
file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar
Splash location:
/Users/aakture/.eclipse/906589807/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/com.jrockit.mc.rcp.application_5.2.0.157284/splash.bmp
Debug options:
file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/Java Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 3
Starting application: 1354
Oct 17, 2013 10:09:30 AM com.jrockit.mc.rcp.application.ApplicationPlugin initializeDebug
INFO: JMC debug mode enabled
Oct 17, 2013 10:09:30 AM com.jrockit.mc.rcp.logging.LoggingToolkit initializeLogging
INFO: Debug settings enabled - loaded debug settings for the logger from logging_debug.properties.
Oct 17, 2013 10:09:30 AM com.jrockit.mc.rcp.logging.LoggingToolkit initializeLogging
FINE: Logger initialized
Oct 17, 2013 10:09:30 AM com.jrockit.mc.jdp.client.Pruner run
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Djava.class.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/Java Mission Control.app/Contents/MacOS//../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
Install location:
file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/missioncontrol/
Configuration file:
FINE: JDP prune thread started!
Oct 17, 2013 10:09:30 AM com.jrockit.mc.common.mbean.LocalMBeanToolkit
FINE: Acquired local PID. PID resolved to 1454
Oct 17, 2013 10:09:31 AM com.jrockit.mc.ui.misc.SwingSupport initLookAndFeel
INFO: Initializing Swing L&F!
!SESSION 2013-10-17 10:09:28.896 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -debug -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-10-17 10:09:35.695
!MESSAGE While loading class "com.jrockit.mc.rjmx.IConnectionDescriptor", thread "Thread[Local Descriptor Scanner,5,main]" timed out waiting (5005ms) for thread "Thread[main,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "com.jrockit.mc.rjmx_5.2.0.157284 [69]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Local Descriptor Scanner,5,main]" is proceeding but "com.jrockit.mc.rjmx.IConnectionDescriptor" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:plugins/com.jrockit.mc.rjmx_5.2.0.157284/" by thread "main".
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1088)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:298)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.jrockit.mc.browser.attach.LocalDescriptorProvider$LocalScanner.scan(LocalDescriptorProvider.java:61)
at com.jrockit.mc.browser.attach.LocalDescriptorProvider$LocalScanner.run(LocalDescriptorProvider.java:44)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
... 17 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1088)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:298)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.jrockit.mc.browser.attach.LocalDescriptorProvider$LocalScanner.scan(LocalDescriptorProvider.java:61)
at com.jrockit.mc.browser.attach.LocalDescriptorProvider$LocalScanner.run(LocalDescriptorProvider.java:44)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-10-17 10:09:40.698
!MESSAGE While loading class "com.jrockit.mc.rjmx.IServerDescriptor", thread "Thread[Local Descriptor Scanner,5,main]" timed out waiting (5002ms) for thread "Thread[main,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "com.jrockit.mc.rjmx_5.2.0.157284 [69]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Local Descriptor Scanner,5,main]" is proceeding but "com.jrockit.mc.rjmx.IServerDescriptor" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:plugins/com.jrockit.mc.rjmx_5.2.0.157284/" by thread "main".
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1088)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:298)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.jrockit.mc.browser.attach.LocalDescriptorProvider$LocalScanner.scan(LocalDescriptorProvider.java:61)
at com.jrockit.mc.browser.attach.LocalDescriptorProvider$LocalScanner.run(LocalDescriptorProvider.java:44)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
... 17 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1088)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:298)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.jrockit.mc.browser.attach.LocalDescriptorProvider$LocalScanner.scan(LocalDescriptorProvider.java:61)
at com.jrockit.mc.browser.attach.LocalDescriptorProvider$LocalScanner.run(LocalDescriptorProvider.java:44)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: I reinstalled, and tried again. I found I can get console output log if I start with both -debug and -consoleLog. Posted output in the original quesion.

Comment: I've seen this myself a couple of times, investigating fixes and workarounds. Klara, JMC Dev

Comment: Thanks Klara, your fix from OTN, which was deleting my ~/.jmc directory fixed it.

Comment: Deleting `~/.jmc` is not a long time solution. Isn't there a real fix available?

Answer (score 0):

There is a proper fix in the upcoming 5.3.0 version of JMC.